# Unable to Resize NTFS Partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, usb, ntfs

I am having a difficult time recovering from a HD failure. Essentially my SSD drive I was using to run Windows 7 for gaming has gone completely haywire. I am trying to resize an NTFS partition on a SATA drive and keep running into issues.

Currently I am following this document - http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu to make a start up USB Disc which I plan to boot off of then resize the NTFS Partition with the ultimate goal of running Windows off this new NTFS Partition.

I've downloaded the Ubuntu 14.04 ISO from ubuntu.com and follow the instructions to step 6 however when I go to select Make Startup Disk the option is still greyed out.

Some information on the situation and my setup.

- Other than a work Windows 7 Laptop with no Admin rights I have no other machines available to me to assist in this process unfortunately.
- I tried resizing the partition with the Windows Boot device but it only give's me an option to format the partition not resize.
- DVD Rom died in the same day as my HD (could be a bigger issue here I am not aware of yet or could be a coincidence).
- Booting of a SATA 3TB Drive
- 1TB Ext4 running Ubuntu 14.04
- 2TB NTFS Partition used to store media, documents etc. This this is the partition I want to resize and create a 2nd NTFS partition to put Windows 7 on and dual boot this way moving forward until I purchase a new SSD Drive.
- USB Device is ADATA Elite S102 Pro which I had previously tested and created a Windows USB Start up disk to install Windows. The device seems to be working fine.
- I've formatted the USB Device using NTFS and Ext4 however I receive the same results (not being able to take the final step to begin the process of creating the USB Ubuntu Boot device.

I've tried to use the "Erase" option in the Startup Disc Creator however I get the following error (same error when the device is formatted in NTFS or Ext4).

```
"org.freedesktop.DBus.Python.gi._glib.GError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/service.py", line 707, in _message_cb
    retval = candidate_method(self, *args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/share/usb-creator/usb-creator-helper", line 239, in Format
    block.call_format_sync('dos', GLib.Variant('a{sv}', {'erase': GLib.Variant('s', '')}), None)
gi._glib.GError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.Failed: Error synchronizing after initial wipe: Timed out waiting for object"
```

Any advice, suggestions and or help would be great I am really stumped right now and burning to play the new Civilizations game. Am I going about this the wrong way? Am I a just being a newb here? I've searched through Ask Ubuntu / Google and have not found this particular scenario discussed which makes me feel like I am doing something incorrectly here.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I would use GParted

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted

Download and create a GParted LiveCD and run from it.

Just be careful and make sure you are working with the right HD when you hit its "apply" button.

GParted makes it pretty simple to resize any partition and there are multiple guides/video's to help explain what you need to do or think about.

Youtube is your friend and there are multiple video guides.   Here is just one:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNoQ6sdES_g